# android script for downloading files from server

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an app that list an array of files in a directory and then allows for the user to open/download any of the files listed.  Any idea where I should start with this?

Comment: I think we're having trouble understanding which device has which role.  Are the files local to the Android device, or are the files local to a server somewhere?  Who is doing the downloading?  A desktop computer?  Or a webserver?

Comment: Seems to me that he is listing file names that are on a sever and when user click any of then it should download to the device.

Comment: Whats an Android "script"?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If yes then please post the relevant code block. We can't write the complete code for you.

Comment: looking at files on a server using an android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try it's code:

```
 private class File_Video extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

        File folders = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/pathofthefile/");
        folders.mkdirs();

        File file;
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/pathofthefile/file_video.txt");


        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            file.delete();
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            return "Downloaded";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

and from onCreate:

```
 File_Video downloadFile_video = new File_Video();

    downloadFile_image.execute("http://youvebsite.com/file1.txt");
```